# RewriteRule for URL News ID

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo

I am kinda stuck with RewriteRule 301, change from OLD News id to new News ID

This is what I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/news/0(.*)$ /news/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Assume the News URL look something like his:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/news/01/title-of-the-new
http://www.mydomain.com/news/09/title-of-the-new
http://www.mydomain.com/news/012/title-of-the-new
http://www.mydomain.com/news/032/title-of-the-new
```

I would like to change to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/news/1/title-of-the-new
http://www.mydomain.com/news/9/title-of-the-new
http://www.mydomain.com/news/12/title-of-the-new
http://www.mydomain.com/news/32/title-of-the-new
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, what sort of results are you getting?

Comment: Ross, It does not redirect from 01 to 1 (Example).

Comment: It might be due to another rule - I just tested this and `http://localhost/news/01/hello` redirects to `http://localhost/news/1/hello`.

Comment: I managed to fix it. Replace `RewriteRule ^/news/0(.*)$ /news/$1 [L,R=301]` to `RewriteRule ^news/0(.*)$ /news/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Glad you fixed it, post this as an answer please :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it replace

```
RewriteRule ^/news/0(.*)$ /news/$1 [L,R=301]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^news/0(.*)$ /news/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need it? Your rule should do the trick, but not that you need (I think). It runs you server-side srcipts whith URL http://www.mydomain.com/news/1/title-of-the-new when you opening  http://www.mydomain.com/news/01/title-of-the-new

Comment: Why do I need it? Because I am redesigning the websites.. currently all the news ID start from 0 (eg: 01, 02, 032, 055, etc). I have used server-side srcipts to add zero from the start. So I decided to remove the 0 and update in the htaccess file for SEO?

Answer (score 0):

I think a more robust rule that removes all pre zeros is a little better:

RewriteRule ^news/0+(.*)$ /news/$1 [L,R=301]